# Dataframe or CSV to JSON object array

Tags: python, json, dataframe, csv

This is probably an easy one for the python pros. So, please forgive my naivety.

Here is my data:

```
0  xyz@tim.com   13239169023       jane        bo
1  tim@tim.com   13239169023       lane        ko
2  jim@jim.com   13239169023       john        do
```

Here is what I get as output:

```
[{"email":"xyz@tim.com","phone_number":13239169023,"first_name":"jane","last_name":"bo"},{"email":"tim@tim.com","phone_number":13239169023,"first_name":"lane","last_name":"ko"},{"email":"jim@jim.com","phone_number":13239169023,"first_name":"john","last_name":"do"}]
```

My Code:

```
    df = pd.read_csv('profiles.csv')
    print(df)
    data = df.to_json(orient="records")
    print(data)
```

**Output I want:**

```
{"profiles":[{"email":"xyz@tim.com","phone_number":13239169023,"first_name":"jane","last_name":"bo"},{"email":"tim@tim.com","phone_number":13239169023,"first_name":"lane","last_name":"ko"},{"email":"jim@jim.com","phone_number":13239169023,"first_name":"john","last_name":"do"}]}
```

Adding below does NOT work.

```
output = {"profiles": data}
```

It adds single quotes on the data and profiles in NOT in double quotes (basically NOT a valid JSON), Like so:

```
{'profiles': '[{"email":"xyz@tim.com","phone_number":13239169023,"first_name":"jane","last_name":"bo"},{"email":"tim@tim.com","phone_number":13239169023,"first_name":"lane","last_name":"ko"},{"email":"jim@jim.com","phone_number":13239169023,"first_name":"john","last_name":"do"}]'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.to_dict` to output to a dictionary instead of a json-formatted string:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data = df.to_dict(orient='records')
output = {'profiles': data}
print(output)
```

Returns:

```json
{'profiles': [{'0': 1, 'xyz@tim.com': 'tim@tim.com', '13239169023': 13239169023, 'jane': 'lane', 'bo': 'ko'}, {'0': 2, 'xyz@tim.com': 'jim@jim.com', '13239169023': 13239169023, 'jane': 'john', 'bo': 'do'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution.

Changes:

```
data = df.to_dict(orient="records")
output = {}
output["profiles"] = data
```